# "Unable to review your site" - AdSense

Tags: google-adsense

Please reply to my question and then close it. Now My life is fully depend upon ad sense.

Yesterday i have submitted my website  for final review of my ad sense account.
But today i received a message saying:

---

As mentioned in our welcome email, we conduct a second review of your AdSense application     once AdSense code is placed on your site(s). As a result of this review, we have disapproved your account for the following violation(s):

Issues:
- **Unable to review your site**

---

Please help me to solve this problem. I am very worrying and tense  about it.
What is the reason for this message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a thread where somebody has the same problem: http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/adsense/_75GSGy3law

It sounds like that message could be caused by:

- if your site requires a viewer to login to see the content
- if your site is using a frame
- if your site is made of flash or using a dynamic blogger template
- if you have too many broken links
- if you are using a redirect
- if your navigation doesn't work
- if your site is having database problems
- if your site's DNS does not resolve

Once your site is up and running publicly, you can resubmit your AdSense review request.

Comment: That could well be the problem.  It looks like you may need a better DNS host.

Comment: i wrote email to my webhosting company , then they replied to me ,saying `On checking the details of the domain name - ansoftsys.com, we see you have added a Child Name servers for the mentioned domain, which is an incorrect record. You have added our Domain Forwarding IP address as the IP address of child name server. We request you to delete the Child name server, which is causing issues with Search engine.` Now i have deleted Child name server. Do you think this will solve my DNS problem?

Comment: Is my last comment is also the part of problem? Or its fine to redirect in this way. Please help me sir, i need your help. Please reply

Comment: I'll bet it is the DNS issue only.  Your redirects don't sound good for user experience and could really hurt your SEO.

Comment: So , now shall i transfer my ansoftsys.com's domain to another company in order to solve this issue. Or shall i transfer both domain &  Web Hosting ?

Comment: You don't need to "transfer" the domain.   That just changes registrar, but won't change either your DNS host or web host.  It sounds like you fixed the problem through your web host, so I'd recommend leaving your hosting as is.

Comment: I made changes as my web host said. But still the DNS error sign(http://i.stack.imgur.com/DQwna.png) is appearing in google webmaster tools.    Does Google takes long time to load new change in order to remove this DNS error?

Comment: Google may take several days to update that graph and remove the warning.

Comment: Thank you, i will wait for that day. If my website is approved, then surely few credits goes to you. You only helped me. I would like to offer you a trip in NEPAL,  to show Nepal famous places.For food & lodge i will pay for you. But you have to manage your travel ticket.

Comment: Sir please help/reply to  my question http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49816/correct-way-of-writing-robots-txt-file

Comment: After solving the above posted issue for adsense, again i applied to Google ad-sense with live blank ads on page, but they disapproved my website by saying "- Insufficient content"  . According to you, what you will give me suggestion for my website(http://ansoftsys.com/) to add content on it, in order to get Adsense?

Comment: Rather than ask additional questions in comments, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Sir i asked here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49862/insufficient-content-adsense    Please help me