# What is the correct way to write my "robots.txt" file?

Tags: robots.txt

I have written the following code inside my *robots.txt* file:

```
   User-Agent: Googlebot
   Disallow:

   User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
   Disallow:

   Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Is my *robots.txt* is correct? I only want two user agent to follow my site (i.e.,  Googlebot & Mediapartners-Google).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost, see the bottom of the section named, "Blocking user-agents" in the following:  [Google Webmaster Tools:  Block or remove pages using a robots.txt file](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449)

According that, you should have:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Allow: /

sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

See the bottom of the page in the above link for how to test your robots.txt file.

Comment: If you're wondering what the difference is between the "Disallow" and "Allow" directives in the above answers, see this: [Allow directive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive) According to that, for Google, an "Allow" directive with equal or more characters than the path of the "Disallow" directive will win. So the above is specific to Google.

Answer (score 2):

Nearly, you need to `Disallow` all the other bots first though.

The wild card (`*`) below means all bots.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow:

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:

Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Although please note, not all web crawlers will obey *robots.txt*.