# “Insufficient content” - AdSense

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

After solving the first  issue for adsense (i.e `“Unable to review your site” - AdSense`),

again i applied to Google ad-sense with live blank ads on page, but In second review they disapproved my website by saying `"- Insufficient content"`  .

What should do now?

Comment: The main issue I see here is that your home page is primarily JavaScript. I would add some HTML content to that which relates to your keywords. The other two pages have more content, but I'd suggest adding more to the second URL that relates to the keywords there too. I don't think there's a "minimum" number of pages for AdSense by the way. So resubmit it after you make the above changes and hopefully it will be OK then.

Comment: One more thing to possibly consider regarding the second URL is hiding the "Read More" text. Since there's so sparse content there, you might as well make sure it's readable.

Comment: @dan how do i make sure whether it is readable or not?

Comment: I haven't looked at the code in detail, but if it's JavaScript that Google can't crawl, then the hidden text won't be seen. I think you just need to add enough content so that when people search for your keywords, Google can display ads that match the keywords searched on and your content.

Comment: @dan i plan to move the 2nd url content to  the first url page and i will place it to just below the converter utility. What you say? is this good?

Comment: If it's visible to you, then it's visible to Google too. When you get content, you can use the Read More, but till then, you  might just display all of it (without hiding any).

Comment: As long as you think that reflects what your site is about and contains content related to your AdSense keywords, then that's an option. Perhaps you should just write something more however so your site grows in unique content (always a plus).

Comment: @dan So did you mean that instead of read more link.. i should display all its content in the same page, without `read more` link?

Comment: That might be wise at this point. As Google indicated, it can't find enough content to support ads.

Comment: @dan I found only  you as a real human being with mankind in this website who is   kind to help people without any benefits. Other help people just help to collect votes or to be genius..

Comment: Thanks - I try :-) I'm sure others here want to help too though. It's just centered around a single question/answer format, and we're not always available to respond right away. But glad to help when I can.

Comment: @dan i applied for Adsense once again for  http://ansoftsys.com/  .As you recommended , i updated my site. Please provide me your opinion once again. -:) Thanks

Comment: OK, but there's a limit the number of comments - we'll need to move this into a chat room to continue further.

Comment: @dan  Before 3 days ago I submitted to ad-sense for second review, but still  no reply from their side. As Adsense docs, it was saying "it will take 2-7 days for final review result. currently i am waiting for their email...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Yahoo answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120708141646AAYNOc3) you should publish at least 30 pages of content on your site with 300-500 words of unique original content per page.

Looking through your site, you have about six pages.  Some of them like "privacy" and "about" don't count as "content".  In the case where your "content" is not text, but rather utility, the word requirement might not apply.

Comment: You said `In the case where your "content" is not text, but rather utility, the word requirement might not apply.` I think same that's why i have not added 30 pages. What could be the reason that they are saying `Insufficient content` for this utility?

Comment: Just one page isn't enough.  You would need many converters to qualify as sufficient content.