# Adsense rejects my blog for difficult site navigation

Tags: google-adsense, navigation, google-adsense-policies, usability

My blog is getting rejected for two things:

1. Insufficient content
2. Difficult site navigation

How can I resolve this problem with difficult site navigation?

Comment: We already have a question and answer here for half of your problem: [“Insufficient content” - AdSense](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49862/insufficient-content-adsense).   We don't get have anything I can find on "difficult navigation".

Comment: There is a relevant discussion on Google's product forums: [Why is Adsense declining us due to difficult site navigation?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/adsense/lVvL2I95ge0/Fb9fjkfvsqcJ)