# How can I create enough content on an e-commerce site to qualify for Google AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense, ecommerce, content, google-adsense-policies

I have an e-commerce site that is basically a catalogue of products. The only pages that have a lot of text are the privacy policy and terms and condition; the rest have images of products with their prices and brief description. I'm getting rejected by Google AdSense because I have *"not enough content"*

How can I add Google AdSense if I have no more content to add to my page other than more products?

Comment: See also [“Insufficient content” - AdSense](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49862/insufficient-content-adsense)?

Comment: Why are you trying to add advertising to an e-commerce site?  Ads on that type of site distract people from purchasing your product.

Comment: Because we want to try it anyways.

Comment: It sounds like your site is suffering from content in more ways than one. Having that little content likely means you're not getting organic visitors, and that the visitors you do get aren't having a very good user experience. Taking the time to generate truly unique product descriptions for every item, and possibly adding additional photos, would go a long way toward improving user experience, improving SEO and the number of visitors, and increasing your conversion rate - and help you get to the point where you can try AdSense if you really want to.

Comment: Try to find the AdSense rules and search for the content topic, there should be all the details.

Comment: Personally I had a lot of headache with AdSense and I still didn't figured it out.